# calling to StreamController.addError after calling StreamController.add gives error

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, streamcontroller

I'm trying to forward a stream results to StreamController, however on calling the 3rd future on the example, the StreamController throws an error with unhelpful message.

This is replicable when I try to call `addError` after calling `add` with values.

Am I missing something?

```
test("stream controller", () async {
    StreamController<int> c = StreamController();

    Future<int> success() async {
      return 1;
    }

    Future<int> throwing() async {
      throw Exception();
    }

    Stream<int>.fromFutures([
      throwing(), // 1
      success(), // 2
      throwing(), // 3
    ]).listen((event) {
      c.add(event);
    }, onError: (e, st) {
      c.addError(e, st);
    });

    await expectLater(
      c.stream,
      emitsInOrder([
        emitsError(isA<Exception>()),
        1,
        emitsError(isA<Exception>()),
      ]),
    );
  });
```

Error:

```
Exception
test/poll_stream_test.dart 115:7  main.<fn>.throwing
test/poll_stream_test.dart 121:7  main.<fn>
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
dart:async                        _StreamController.addError
test/poll_stream_test.dart 125:9  main.<fn>.<fn>
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
dart:async                        _StreamImpl.listen
test/poll_stream_test.dart 122:8  main.<fn>
```

I have no idea why this doesn't works, but I'm expecting the StreamController to successfully emits error after I emits some value.

Comment: I would just use `c.stream.listen(..., onError: ...)` and see what `c.stream` gives you, when I called that, it turned out that 2 errors came first followed by a normal value (so the order was changed)

Comment: when I listened to the stream, it emits the items in correct order, however when using `expectLater` matcher it causes error

Comment: Huh, it's indeed the first 2 exception is printed first, and then the normal value.

Comment: but when you do `=> Future.value(i * 2);` the order is correct, maybe try the same "trick" in your code and check `expectLater` again?

Comment: Yes, it's working correctly now. But is there a way to not wrap the value in `Future.value` because I need the future to be passed from other code. I tried to use `Stream.fromIterable` and `asyncMap` the future, but it causes error when the future throws

Comment: I think the problem is only when you `return someValue` - if you return a `Future` from somewhere else it should work imho

Comment: Ah I see, so in test the function should return `Future.value`. I'll have to test this. Thanks for your help!

Comment: your welcome, but honestly I have no idea why this happens...